# linux fork communication

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have a parent process and n child processes that wait so receive something from the network.The thing is that for every message received by the child from the network I need to tell the father what the message contains.If I try to make a pipe or a socketpair between the father and the children then then the father doesn't know where a message ends and where another begins.Can you please help ?

Comment: Have a look at IPC (InterProcessCommunication). There are many possibilities (shared mem, pipes, ...).

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't know where a message ends and where another begins"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to define your own protocol for sending messages.

Comment: Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using stream oriented pipes/socket pair. So you lose message boundaries.

Use datagram oriented sockets for keeping message boundaries.

See mapage [unix(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) for more information about datagram based unix sockets and socketpairs.

There are functions that may suit for you:

```
   socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, int *sv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before writing into pipe or socketpair use some delimeter so that every child adds that delimeter to the message before sending to the father